# Invalid Taxonomy Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have created a custom taxonomy which is working fine. Below are the code:

```
add_action('init', 'canderel_game_taxonomy', 0);

function canderel_game_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Gamme',
        'singular_name' => 'Gamme',
        'search_items' =>  'Recherche Gamme',
        'all_items' => 'Toutes les Gammes',
        'parent_item' => 'Gamme Parent',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Gamme Parent',
        'edit_item' => 'Editer Gamme',
        'update_item' => 'Enregistrer Gamme',
        'add_new_item' => 'Nouvelle Gamme',
        'menu_name' => 'Gammes'
    );

    register_taxonomy('gammes', array('produit'), array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'gamme' ),
    ));
}
```

Here is my code to fetch the taxonomy term but it is returning invalid taxonomy everytime.

```
$terms = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => 'gammes',
    'hide_empty' => false,
]);
```

Comment: Where do you call `get_terms`? If it's inside some hook it might be too early. Change that priority to 10: `add_action('init', 'canderel_game_taxonomy', 10);` and try with that

Comment: @GMarco24  It works. Thanks. I was calling the `get_terms` inside a plugin.